# Hbase-client kerberos authentication working only on local computer

Tags: java, hbase, kerberos, hbase-client

I developed a spring application, which uses hbase-client 2.1.1 to authenticate to kerberized hbase with a keytab.

On my local computer I can authenticate successfully and retrieve data, but when I deploy it to a wildfly server I get the following error:

```
[0m[0m11:58:56,216 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 253) Looking for keys for: MYUSER@REAL.COM
[0m[0m11:58:56,217 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 253) HBase create connection failed: java.io.IOException: Login failure for MYUSER@REAL.COM from keytab /home/risorse/S0008533/fc.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

The keytab is the same, the path is correct and I don't know where to check for other logs.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Enable kerberos debug logs in java via JVM option: -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you validate that the user that is trying to use the keytab file can kinit with it. (Does the keytab file have the correct permissions?)

Login as the user that the server will be using the keytab as and perform:

```
kinit -kt /home/risorse/S0008533/fc.keytab MYUSER@REAL.COM
```

It's likely the case that the spring application user should own the keytab.  This is a Really common thing I forget to do all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much! the problem was the ownership. With kinit I saw a permission error and I fixed it with chown.